# CONCAT string to longblog and mysql disk usage

Tags: mysql, innodb

If I am an innodb table that this query executes a lot (once every second for some time with a small amount of data appended) and have `innodb_files_per_table = 0` can this cause a problem with storage? The blob itself could be 2-3MB but I lost 30gb of data usage and am wondering if this code is to blame in any way or if I should be looking somewhere else.

SQL

```
UPDATE phppos_app_files 
SET file_data = CONCAT(file_data, "NEW LINE OF DATA")
WHERE file_id = 10;
```

Schema:

```
mysql> show create table phppos_app_files;
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_app_files | CREATE TABLE `phppos_app_files` (
  `file_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_data` longblob NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The data stored in blog column is 2-3 mb of log text; just plain text. My question I am asking though is if frequent update queries where you concat from the current value cause storage issues where it causes huge problems with database. I just want to make sure it only stores the least amount of info and if an update with concat can cause any huge disk issues.

Comment: without knowing more about what you store into file_data, we cannot identify issue.

Comment: it is 2-3mb of plain log data

Comment: can you check my answer before going further, because we first need to make sure that this is the table which is causing trouble

Comment: How many times did you add a small string to that blob before 27930.00MB vanished?  In other words, I am fishing for a _reproducible_ test case.

Comment: It is really hard to say. I have many databases and I would say 4 or 5 of them had some activity with this type of logging. But then I got thinking that sessions are stored as a blob too and are updated frequently and have never had issue, when this storage issue happened this was the major backend change made recently. I could be wrong but have nothing else to point to. Are their any other reasons to have MySQL just claim a bunch of space? Any commands I can run to show you any more data?

Comment: The one log i did check with 3mb after 10 minutes to create it

Comment: Also to note thar my cross region replica never had a drop in storage space

Comment: Could you post results of SELECT file_id, file_data FROM phppos_app_files WHERE file_id=10;  so we can see your current content for this one file_id? 
Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5eaco230zcrop0/file_id_10.txt?dl=0

Comment: @ChrisMuench - What is the value of `binlog_format`?

Comment: At 3MB/sec, 3 hours would chew up 30GB.  I'm still confused as to how much data (3MB?) is added how often (1/sec? 1/10-minutes?) to how many tables(1?  1000?).

Comment: 3MB total file in 3 hours (I read the log wrong). We are adding it line by line such as 12/26/2018 10:40:02 : *******Exception: 'Error:  []' as shown in file above

Comment: Could you post results of SELECT * FROM phppos_app_files WHERE file_id=7570; so we can see your current row content for this one file_id? Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5eaco230zcrop0/file_id_10.txt?dl=0

Comment: The above link is the binary log for 3 hours.  I would like the data from one row of the table, please.

Comment: That is one row; it is just a big string. That is the file_data blob for that row

Comment: @ChrisMuench Since this is the data for one file_id and the blob grew to 3MB in 3 hours, in less than 2 hours, you will exceed the max of LONGBLOB and there is no provision in the update to deal with the expected error.  (LONGBLOB max is 4MB).  This live logging method for your 7,000+ file ID's will be very consuming for your storage requirements and as is, will use ~ 8,000 * 4MB = 32GB of space and be out of date in a matter of hours per active file_id.  Another negative side effect is the overhead for INNODB to deal with storing this data 'off row'.

Comment: Long blob can hold 4gb; it doesn’t seem possible that a 3mb file can cause 32gb of space consumption

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to storing and accessing BLOBs, frequent updates of small data chunks can result in lot of space being wasted due to fragmentation. There are possible optimizations to consider :

- compress before storing, as [explained in this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-blob.html) (could be relevant for your use case, as your BLOB stores text)
- periodically run an [OPTIMIZE TABLE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html), to reorganize the physical storage. As commented by Bill Karwin, with option `innodb_file_per_table` disabled this will not shrink the tablespace. However it will reclaim space lost due to fragmentation and mark it as available within the tablespace : so it will repurpose any empty extents before it grows the tablespace again.

Comment: Could this explain 30gb of lost free space?

Comment: @ChrisMuench : fragmentation could explain that. Right now you want to OPTMIZE TABLE and check its size afterwards...

Comment: Does optimize table have any affect on storage size with Innodb file per table 0. I have many databases

Comment: Yes optmize table will work even if inondb_file_per_table is set to 0

Comment: Will it reclaim space?

Comment: @ChrisMuench... yes that’s what OPTIMIZE TABLE does... Did you read the doc that I linked ? It explains the purpose of this command

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLES` does defragment, but it can't shrink a tablespace, unless you use `innodb_file_per_table=1`. A multi-table tablespace will never shrink. It can only mark empty extents as ready to be reused for future data. So it will repurpose any empty extents before it grows the tablespace again.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for pointing this out... I updated my answer

Comment: @ChrisMuench : I updated my answer with more details on ANALYZE TABLE

Comment: @GMB - I see no mention of `ANALYZE`.

Comment: @RickJames : sorry I meant OPTMIZE

Answer (score 1):

If you make frequent updates of large blobs, it could indeed use a lot of storage temporarily, and leave your tablespace fragmented.

An update copies the original data pages to the "undo log" which is just an area of pages in the tablespace. InnoDB keeps these copied pages in case you rollback your transaction and have to restore the original data. After you commit your update, the copy in the undo log is not needed anymore, and InnoDB will gradually clean up. But if your updates are frequent as you say, you could be accumulating garbage in the undo log faster than InnoDB can clean it out.

In any case, expanding the storage for more undo log content will grow the tablespace, and even after InnoDB cleans up, the tablespace will not shrink. It'll always remain the size of its high-water mark.

To mitigate this, MySQL 5.6 introduced an option to allow the undo log to be stored outside the system tablespace, and MySQL 5.7 introduced a feature to truncate undo logs after they're cleaned up. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-undo-tablespaces.html for more information on these features.

---

If you're interested in the internal layout of InnoDB files, I recommend trying out the open-source tools Jeremy Cole wrote: https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby/wiki

You can dump various summaries of what's in your ibdata1 tablespace. A lot of the file could be unused, but still taking space.

Here's an example from my local MySQL sandbox. I just have one table with `innondb_file_per_table=0` (all the other tables are outside the central tablespace). I ran this command:

```
innodb_space -s /usr/local/var/mysql/ibdata1 -T mydatabase/mytable space-extents-illustrate
```

Here's the illustration it created. The legend (not included) showed that the data and indexes for my one table fell in the pages between 3008 and 3392. The other stuff was mostly InnoDB system data structures (black), system tables, insert buffers (dark yellow), and unoccupied pages (grey).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query to check size of your tables. In this way you can see which table is wasting your storage.

```
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC
```

---

indeed, The total amount of space used stays same.

If you use `innodb_files_per_table=0` you will have only one tablespace and since your data is changing quickly there is a possibility that your tablespace get fragmented in time.

If you decide in future to drop or truncate your table, your tablespace size will remain same (does not shrink) hence you cannot regain the space from drop operation.

Comment: This shows what I would expect in terms of data sizes; but I am guess I am concerned if the query above can fill up free space since I am using innodb_file_per_table of 0

Comment: 27930.00MB is my free space as found from mysql> SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') DATA_Space, 
    ->  CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space, create_time, table_rows, engine, create_options  
    ->  from information_schema.TABLES 
    ->  where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and Data_free > 0
    ->  ORDER BY FLOOR ( FREE_Space ) DESC, FLOOR ( DATA_Space ) DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    -> ;

Comment: Just wondering if this query can contribute to excess free space or if I should be looking somewhere else

Comment: So if I am updating a lot this can cause a possible of heavy fragmentation and possible storage issues? If I enable file per table would I not have this issue?

Comment: if you enable, you want have this issue on your other tables. If you keep it disabled then you will store all your tables into one tablespace and when your tablespace get fragmented, it will affect all your tables.

Comment: I don’t understand last statement; is there a typo?

Comment: if you enable, you wont have fragmentation issue on other tables. If you keep it disabled then you will store all your tables into one tablespace and when your tablespace get fragmented, this will affect all your tables

Comment: So would your recommendation be not to update blobs a lot or use file per table of 1?

Comment: Also how does mysql decided when to start eating up space. It seemed like it happened hours after the blob updates